# Visual Studio - Adding two web references

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, visual-studio-2012, asmx

I'm using VS2012 and have successfully added a service reference to a web service, lets call it Web Service A. I can connect and interact with that webservice, it all works ok.

There's another version of the webservice (Web Service B) that I need to connect to, it's essentially the same but one is used for live and the other for testing. The URLs are different so I thought I could add a second reference without an issue.

However, when I do add Web Service B everything appears to work fine (web.config is modified etc.) but all my existing code that interacts with Web service A breaks, visual studio acts like it doesn't know what classes I'm trying to instantiate.

Can I have two very similar web references (different URLs) that I can easily switch between by changing the code? I would have thought I could but maybe not?

Comment: What kind of web service you are using ? asmx ? wcf, you can change the URL at runtime I believe.

Comment: Did you use a web reference, or a service reference? Web References are the client side of ASMX. ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: Sorry, should have been clearer, I added a service reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a Service or Web Reference, along with all the code that VS create, the important bit is this thing in the web.config (or App.Config):

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="TempConvertSoap" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="TempConvertSoap12">
                <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
                <httpTransport />
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx"
                  binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TempConvertSoap"
                  contract="ServiceReferenceA.TempConvertSoap" name="TempConvertSoap" />
        <endpoint address="http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx"
                  binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="TempConvertSoap12"
                  contract="ServiceReferenceA.TempConvertSoap" name="TempConvertSoap12" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

The example is from the Temperature Convesion service in w3schools.

In your scenario, you only need to add a single web reference and then, to connect to the other one, change this section, in particular the `endpoint -> address` attribute; **as long as the webservice are IDENTICAL**, it will work without problems.

As a bonus, being part of the web.config or app.config, you could use config tranforms to replace this with the proper address when building your Release.

Comment: When you say that all I need to do is edit that section, what edits do I need to make? When I added the new web service reference VS automatically made the edits for me. And then all my code broke....

Comment: Sorry, I mean edit the `endpoint` address. This edit should only happen when you deploy, so do not add two services, add only one and change the endpoint address based on which one you want to use.

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a go. In the project I'm working on these references are added in the App_webReferences folder, but I add them by adding a Service Reference. It's confusing but will editing that endpoint also update the files in that App_webreferences folder?

Comment: Editing the endpoint will not trigger any editing to your code! :) That's the beauty of it. You add a reference to a service and VS creates all the code for you (mind it's just proxy classes in the end)... you then want to connect to an **identical** service at a different address? change the address and the existing code will still work.

Answer (score 0):

If one is for live and another for test, I would add web.config transformations and then run your code under a 'test' configuration.

More info on web.config transforms here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx